# Typo3 - Two folders with same uid?

Tags: directory, typo3, uid

i have two folders with the same uid.One is at the root level and one is inside the page tree:

```
-page
 -page1
  -folder
-folder
```

They are connected (if i deactivate one the other is deactivated aswell, logical same id). 
In the database there is only one entry(logical again same id).

How do i get rid of the folder outside of the root? I don't know how this could happen..

If someone has a solution to this tricky problem, i'm done.

Comment: Sounds like a corruption in the DB . Did you try deleting the connected folders and making a new one

Comment: It could also be a mountpoint - can you check the type of both pages, is it really "folder" in both cases?

Comment: I think that @Jost is right, I had such situation on some old installation, just mounting points where displayed on page tree twice, most probably you have a user/usergroup who has access only to the `folder` and as a side effect "full admin" see this mp as a separate page. See this: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/25381. Note: it;s hard to detect if the second instance is a mount point, as during editing by it forwards you to properties of the original page.

Answer (score 0):

Just checked my old installation with the same case: you can see the same page/folder twice in tree (de facto outer one is a *DB mount point*) because your account has access to the mount point - and also to the page itself.

Most possible:

- you're logged as a full admin so you can see both at once AND you included the mount point in your settings (see screenshot)
- you checked **DB mounts from group** to the admin
- your BE user is not an admin, but has assigned DB mounts for both - root page and inner folder.

Check it, go to the user's properties and make sure that admin hasn't included mount points and doesn't mount DB points from groups:

**You don't need to add these for full admin as he/she has access to whole tree anyway**

[image: You don't need to add these for full admin as he/she has access to whole tree anyway]

Note: Actually credits should go to Jost for valid clue ;)